# independece of product of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Suppose that $X\sim U[0,1],Y\sim U[0,1]$ and $Z \sim U[0,1]$ are independent random variables.
Is it true that:

$$XY, YZ$$

are independent as well? I am pretty sure that the answer is yes, however, I can't find a way to prove it. Hints are more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If random variables $U$, $V$ are independent, then
$$ E(UV) = E(U) E(V).$$